# I can't get Catel.sln to load its projects

Tags: catel

I cloned the catel repo, opened `Catel.sln` in VS 2019, and switched to master branch. None of the projects load. In the Solution output window I'm getting messages like

`\Catel.Tests.TestReferenceC\Catel.Tests.TestReferenceC.csproj : error  : The expression "[System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName('')" cannot be evaluated. The path is not of a legal form.`

for each project in the solution. The message also mentions

`.nuget\packages\msbuild.sdk.extras\2.0.54\Sdk\Sdk.props`

It looks like the problem is in `msbuild.sdk.extras`. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check out the section in the readme about building Catel:

https://github.com/catel/catel#building-catel

MSBuild.Sdk.Extras is required as sdk for the projects (allows multi-targeting and more). The most important thing is to restore packages. Once packages (especially MSBuild.Sdk.Extras) are restored, it should work as expected.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like .NET Core 3.0 Preview SDK isn't available. I downloaded & installed .NET Core 3.0 SDK (v3.0.103) and all the projects opened. Thanks.